# Customize the default Android Camera preview screen?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am working on an Android app mainly based around the camera of the device. I am able to launch and use the Camera Intent but I would like to know if there is a way to customize this camera screen. I mean, for the moment, the camera preview screen displays all the settings of the camera, I would like to be able to hide them. If possible, I would also like to add new buttons on this screen, so I could launch popups or display a message to the user. Is it possible or should I try to use an external library which handles that ?

Basically, I would like to have a camera screen which would look like the one from the Snapchat Android app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a way to customize this camera screen

No. After all, there are several hundred possible applications that you could be launching, and none of them have to offer any sort of API for the control that you want.

> I would like to have a camera screen which would look like the one from the Snapchat Android app.

Then use the camera APIs directly (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`) and write your own camera app.